# Как запустить один файл стилей по клику а второй отключить?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне необходимо на одной странице вывести контент двух лендов
Я использую такой метод:

```
    $( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#article-post').show();
    $('#chat-content').hide();
    $('#go-chat').click(function () {
                $('#article-post').hide();
                $('#chat-content').fadeIn('fast');
            });

})
```

Первый ленд оборачивается в тег с идентификатором article-post
Второй соответственно оборачивается в тег с идентификатором chat-content

В первом ленде вставляю для подгрузки.

```
<div id="chat-content">
        <?php
  include_once('chat.php');
?>
</div>
```

На первом ленде кнопка с id go-chat которая и запускает данную конструкцию.

Но, тут возникает проблема со стилями, стили первого ленда и второго перемешиваются и получается каша, т.к у обоих имеются глобальные теги типа body, h1 и т.д

Использую такой способ т.к нужно передать данные clickid с первого ленда, на второй. Просто в переменную clickid занести нельзя.

Вопрос, возможно ли как-то по клику на кнопку отключить файл стилей первого ленда и запустить файл стилей второго ленда.

Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь, возможно вы знаете более адекватное решение.

Comment: Сделать можно на js, покажите, как формируются теги со стилями у вас. Хотя логичее сразу в php формировать нужные теги с указанием нужных файлов стилей

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу выкладывать сюда код, По формированию как и обычный любой html. В head подключаются стили, а дальше тело с p/div тегами, ничего особенного.

Comment: Ну тогда обращаетесь к тегу, где подключаются стили и меняете ему href на нужный. Для удобства, добавьте id.

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: Это даст нужный вам результат в виде закгрузки нового файла стилей с выгрузкой предыдущего 